# Updating the parameters of the Viterbi Algorithmm

Tags: markov-chains

I am currently studying Viterbi Algorithm within the context of probability and sequence generation. My understanding of it so far, is that it helps us generate a sequence of events such that it is most likely to cause a specific sequence of observed events. My question now is, is it possible for me to find the initial state, emission and transition probabilities such that it generates a specific sequence of events that I want it to? I know that the algorithm takes (Number of States)^2 * T, where T is the length of the sequence. If anyone could help me solve such a problem I'd be highly grateful thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you, at the moment I do not have any relavent mathematical notation to add on here, but I see where (Number Of States)^2 * T could be better

Comment: Yes, it could be $(\text{Number Of States})^2\times T$.